# Boto3 Not Locating Credentials with DynamoDB Encryption SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, boto3

For some reason, the credentials supplied in boto3's Session is not being picked up the `EncryptedTable` method of `dynamodb-encryption-sdk`. The same credentials work if I just use the unecrypted table method direct from boto3.

```
import boto3
from dynamodb_encryption_sdk import EncryptedTable
from dynamodb_encryption_sdk.material_providers.aws_kms import AwsKmsCryptographicMaterialsProvider
from environs import Env

env = Env()
env.read_env('local.env', False)

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=env('AWS_ACCESS_ID'),
                        aws_secret_access_key=env('AWS_SECRET_KEY'),
                        region_name=env('AWS_REGION'))

dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('accounts-table')

aws_cmk_id = env('AWS_CMK_ID')
aws_kms_cmp = AwsKmsCryptographicMaterialsProvider(key_id=aws_cmk_id)

encrypted_table = EncryptedTable(
    table=table,
    materials_provider=aws_kms_cmp,
)

plaintext_item = {
    'account_id': '4548',
    'account_name': 'Blah',
}

encrypted_table.put_item(Item=plaintext_item)
```

This is what I get while executing this code:

```
  File "/Users/nirmalnatarajan/venvs/account-postman/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: If you name your .env variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` then they should be picked up automatically and you won't need a session.

Comment: @AlexHall, wow that did the work! Can you please make that an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your .env variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` then they will be picked up automatically from `os.environ` and you don't need a session.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in the `session` to the [AwsKmsCryptographicMaterialsProvider](https://aws-dynamodb-encryption-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lib/materials_providers/aws_kms.html):

```py
aws_kms_cmp = AwsKmsCryptographicMaterialsProvider(key_id=aws_cmk_id,
                                                   botocore_session=session)
```

Alternatively, I think you could set it as [the default session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/boto3.html#boto3.setup_default_session).